# Are Angular.js curly brackets safe to display user input from an input field?

Tags: angularjs, xss

Let's assume we have an Angular app page with the following line:

```
 <div class="item-name">{{person.FirstName}}</div>
```

Lower down the user is allowed to change the first name.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input ng-model="person.FirstName" type="text">
</md-input-container>
```

If I put any html or naughty values like  `<script>console.log(1)</script>` the div doesn't show parsed input but the actual string. This seems is good.

Is this safe at all?

Can this be exploited? (e.g. I am aware of operator overloading tricks -- would such a trick work here?)

I cannot seem to find any official or respectable information that says that this is safe, recommended or maybe not recommended.

Comment: You can safely assume that it is safe, if you need to have html string displayed, you'll need to use `$sce` service

Comment: angular does by default protect you from script injection... so its safe..

Comment: @lcycool - how do you know for sure?

Comment: @Tymski why don't you test by yourself?

Comment: @The_ehT I did - I'm no security expert though.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS expressions are sandboxed.

> ### Expression Sandboxing
>
> AngularJS's expressions are sandboxed not for security reasons, but instead to maintain a proper separation of application responsibilities. For example, access to window is disallowed because it makes it easy to introduce brittle global state into your application.
>
> However, this sandbox is not intended to stop attackers who can edit the template before it's processed by Angular. It may be possible to run arbitrary JavaScript inside double-curly bindings if an attacker can modify them.
>
> But if an attacker can change arbitrary HTML templates, there's nothing stopping them from doing:
>
> ```
> <script>somethingEvil();</script>
> ```
>
> It's better to design your application in such a way that users cannot change client-side templates.
>
> For instance:
>
> - Do not mix client and server templates
> - Do not use user input to generate templates dynamically
> - Do not run user input through `$scope.$eval`
> - Consider using CSP (but don't rely only on CSP)

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Security - Expression Sandboxing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security#expression-sandboxing)

AngularJS Expressions are sandboxed not for security reasons, but the sandboxing does increase security. Angular Expressions are limited to variable and functions that are on `$scope`. Angular Expressions can't access global functions or global variables.

Comment: The first sentence in this article says: AngularJS's expressions are sandboxed not for security reasons :/

Answer (score 0):

There is some hint in the official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

> Typically, you don't use ngBind directly, but instead you use the
>   double curly markup like {{ expression }} which is similar but less
>   verbose.
>
> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a
>   template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state
>   before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it
>   makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

**Performance:**

The {{}} is much slower.

This ng-bind is a directive and will place a watcher on the passed variable. So the ng-bind will only apply, when the **passed value does actually change**.

The brackets on the other hand will be **dirty checked** and refreshed in **every** $digest, even if it's **not necessary**.

The double curly brace notation {{ }} to bind expressions to elements is built-in Angular markup.

**it is secure to use** 
you can visit here more information - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question about how secure it is :)